# csvファイルがうまくダウンロードできない場合の対処法につきまして

Tags: 機械学習

機械学習初心者の学生です。

電力データ分析を行おうと思い、下記リンクにアクセスしたのですが、
なぜかcsvファイルがダウンロードできず、web上に表示されるだけでした。
http://www.tepco.co.jp/forecast/html/images/juyo-2018.csv

web上の情報をコピペしてエクセルに貼り付けたのですが、複数の情報が1セルにまとめられて表示されてしまいます。

機械: 64bit windows OS
ブラウザ: Google Chrome　です。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv`ファイルが開かれてしまったページを"名前を付けて保存"で保存し、保存したファイルの拡張子がもしも`.csv`になっていなければ、拡張子を`.csv`にリネームしてからエクセルで開くと、ちゃんと、1セル1データーのエクセルファイルになると思います。

Comment: ご指摘頂きました方法で無事csvファイルをダウンロードできました！本当にありがとうございました！

Comment: 補足させていただきますと、ブラウザーによって、リンク先の拡張子によって、ダウンロードするのか、ブラウザー自身で表示するのかを設定する項目があるブラウザーもあります。方法はWeb検索を行って頂きたいのですが、ブラウザーによっては、設定で`.csv`ファイルはブラウザーで表示せずにダウンロードさせることが出来ると思います

Comment: 補足ありがとうございます。エクスプローラーでも試してみたのですが、直接ダウンロードできなかったので今回ご質問いたしました。